# C# OAuth OWIN: return custom response when invalid credentials provided to Token endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, owin

I have a Web API project which implements authentication via `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. I've subclassed the provider and have implemented methods as necessary to implement my own authentication system.

I also have figured out how to override the return value provided for unauthenticated requests (you have to subclass the `AuthorizeAttribute` class and then use your custom attribute instead of `Authorize` on endpoints you intend to secure).

I can also override the `TokenResponse` method in my OAuth auth server provider in order to alter the response containing the token.

Now what I'm trying to do is to override the response provided by the token endpoint when a user provides *incorrect* credentials to the token endpoint. Right now, I simply get this:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."}
```

I know where this text is coming from - in my `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method I do the following if a request is not authenticated:

```
if (!isValidUser)
{         
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
    return;
}
```

Instead though, I want to be able to fully manipulate the `Response` object that is returned when the user provides incorrect credentials.

As an example, I might want to set the return to look like this:

```
{"error":401,"timestamp":1234567890,"message":"Those credentials are wrong. Try again."}
```

Is there a way to override the response that the server provides upon *failed* authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this behaviour. You only can change the fields in `context.SetError()` method.

In this case the response, including the status code, is composed in `SendErrorAsJsonAsync()` private method, inside [`OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler`](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs) internal class, in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` dll.

You can revise the code in [`OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler`](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs) class for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099234/owin-oauth-differentiate-expired-and-invalid-token)

```
public class CustomAccessTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
        var expired = context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc < DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (expired)
        {
            //If current token is expired, set a custom response header
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-AccessTokenExpired", new string[] { "1" });
        }

        base.Receive(context);
    }
}
```

Register it when setting up OWIN OAuth:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AccessTokenProvider = new CustomAccessTokenProvider()
            });
```